# Correct locations of BOOST_ROOT and BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR on OSX (brew)?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm building with CMake, I get the error Boost can't be found. I'm using Boost 1.68.0 on OSX installed by brew. I'm told the best way to configure CMakeList.txt is to just set `BOOST_ROOT` and `BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR`. Please excuse my ignorance, but which directories are those referring to?

I'm guessing they are one of the one's I've guessed bellow.

```
losers-mbp:Cellar loser$ pwd
/usr/local/Cellar
losers-mbp:Cellar loser$ tree -L 3 boost/
boost/
└── 1.68.0          <--- Is this BOOST_ROOT?
    ├── INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
    ├── include
    │   └── boost   <--- Or is this BOOST_ROOT?
    │       ├── accumulators
    │       ├── algorithm
    │       ├── align
    │       ├── align.hpp
    │       ├── aligned_storage.hpp
    │       ... more source files
    └── lib                        <--- I'm guessing this is BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR
        ├── libboost_atomic-mt.a
        ├── libboost_atomic-mt.dylib
        ├── libboost_chrono-mt.a
        ├── libboost_chrono-mt.dylib
        ... more binaries
```

Regardless, I've tried to build with this CMake file:

```
# About this build.
project(webtest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
# Tell me what I need.
find_package(Boost 1.68.0 COMPONENTS asio REQUIRED)
# Set paths info.
set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/include")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0")
set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/lib")
# Include things.
include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# Build it.
add_executable(webtest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(webtest ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
```

The error I get says my include path is `/usr/local/include` when I specifically told it to look in in `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/include`, so it's not even looking where I tell it to.

```
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2048 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.68.0

  Boost include path: /usr/local/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_asio

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
```

For `BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS`, I also tried the following paths `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/include/boost`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe `1.68.0` is BOOST_ROOT. And that is the only variable you need to set. Also the variable should be set before find_package() or via the cmake-gui or ccmake

Comment: `find_package(Boost 1.68.0 COMPONENTS asio REQUIRED)` after this does not find boost the configure step ends with the fatal error. Lines after it are not processed.